# HTML/JS - Asking the user to input a number, then displaying a different page on the same site based on the input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using HTML, CSS and JS to build a website, the website has many functions and one important function is that i want to ask the user to manually enter a number from 1 to 40, then once the number is inputted the page changes to display a different page on the same website with information based on the inputted number. One way im thinking of doing is using a form then making the action be a switch statement for all 40 pages. But i'm struggling to find anything similar on Google or Youtube. And im unsure how to link the switch statement to my form, if that would even work. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect than you can add this line `window.location.replace("<your link to page>");` in a function and call it when the user clicks the submit button. and make sure to pass the number to the page to process it. (this might be easier if you use php too, but won't be hard with javascript as far as i know)